# How update a forked repository downloaded as zip and modified locally

Tags: git, github, repository, fork, repo

I have forked a public repository then downloaded it as zip and modified it.
Unfortunately now that i want to update the remote one by my modified local repo, I get so many problems and merge conflicts.
My method to do this is as follows:

1. initialize a local repo in my project directory
2. add the remote repo to local one
3. make the branch names compatible (master/main)
4. add and commit the new changes to my local repo
5. pull the remote repo
6. lots of merge conflicts and, even when solving them, did not get my results.

Is there any better method, to use my current modifications and not starting again by cloning the forked repo and so on...?

Comment: Why don't you clone your fork, instead of downloading a zip?! I'd recommend reading https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks

Comment: @jonrsharpe At first i did not know that i want to do these modifications and then update its remote. So now that have done so much, I wish if I could hold them and not repeat the process from the beginning as 
 you suggested .